# Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

(Apologize for my english) Hey, I wanted to create a channel after command executes.
After executing command, it shows me the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')
```

My ticket.js code below

```js
const {
    Client,
    SlashCommandBuilder,
    PermissionFlagsBits,
    GatewayIntentBits
} = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds]
});

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ticket')
        .setDescription('Utwórz ticketa'),
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        interaction.guild.channels.create({
            name: `ticket`,
            type: ChannelType.GuildText,
            parent: cat[0].ID
            // your permission overwrites or other options here

        });

    }
};
```

Comment: Your code is trying to read the property `channels` from `interaction.guild`. The error indicates that `interaction.guild` is `undefined`. You'll have to check the API documentation why `interaction.guild` is `undefined` and determine if it can legally be `undefined` (in this case, you write code to guard against it) or if it's not expected to be `undefined` (in this case, find out what other thing is causing it to be).